# Present modal VC under tabbar, from tabbar controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have to present a modal VC under a tabbar. I Have to present it from a tabbar controller

```
player.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:player animated:YES completion:^{
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tabBar];


    }];
```

That's my code. In this case my model VC covers the tabbar. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You will have to manually add the new view as a subview of the tab bar controller's view and animate the view into place yourself, keeping it below the tab bar.

Comment: You want the user to be able to switch tabs, while one tab has a modal presented?

Comment: Yes, with @keithbhunter's answer i've solved my problem, very thanks